# Can't use opkg on pre-configured embedded machine

Tags: opkg

I want to add a feature to a pre-configured embedded machine with `uname -a` output:

```
Linux asdf 3.1.10 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 11 02:05:03 CET 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

It uses busybox for a lot of its terminal commands and has a lot of stuff that doesn't work. It uses `opkg` as its package manager. I wanted to update `systemd` the other day and so I typed `opkg update`, which gave

```
Downloading http://www.website-of-manufacturer.com/ipk2/all/Packages.gz.
wget: bad address 'website-of-manufacturer.com:8008'
```

So I wanted to update the list of repositories, which should be done by editing `/etc/opkg.conf` if I understand correctly. But there is no such file. So after reading [this](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/opkg#adjust_repositories) I simply created it and pasted the example from the link.

But after running `opkg update` again, it still looks for `http://www.website-of-manufacturer.com/ipk2/all/Packages.gz`! What can I do to remove this repo and add others?

Edit: I also tried `grep -Ril website-of-manufacturer` in rootdir, but the installed version of grep doesn't support those flags so I don't even know where the configuration file is located :D

Edit: Ok `find ./ -type f | xargs grep "website-of-manufacturer"` actually located the file I was looking for. I guess I'll answer my own question if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Since `grep -r` was not working, I could not find the config file. But then I tried

```
find ./ -type f | xargs grep "website-of-manufacturer"
```

which located the file containing the repository list. Neat trick for environments where `grep` isn't working like it should.